# how to cancel a function after a while?

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I want to know how can I cancel a function after a certain time!

for example, how can I cancel this function?

```
private async Task function()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //mycode
            }
        }
        catch{ }
    }
```

Comment: You've tagged the question with `CancellationTokenSource` - so pass a CancellationToken into the function, and on each iteration of the loop check it to see if cancellation has been requested, i.e. `while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) { …`

Answer (score 2):

> how can I cancel this function?

Normally, awaitable methods will take a `CancellationToken`, so you'd just pass it on through:

```
private async Task functionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  while (true)
  {
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken); //mycode
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago i faced the same issue and found a pretty good solution working for me. I am separating async calls to another service via wcf this way (see my code below) by doing two things to cancel after a maximum time:

You can use CancellationToken in combination with a second Task to run parallel to your running task and cancel it if necessary:

```
    private const int TimeOut = 50000;

    public static async Task<T> HandleServiceCall<T>(Func<Task<T>> doServiceCall, CancellationTokenSource source) where T : class
    {
        var delaySource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50));
        source.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var res = doServiceCall();

        if (await Task.WhenAny(res, Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(TimeOut), delaySource.Token)) == res)
        {
            delaySource.Cancel();
            await res;
        }
        else
        {
            source.Cancel();
            throw new Exception("Your Text");
        }

        return await res;
    }
```

You can call this Method for example this way:

```
    var source = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50));
    source.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    MyWrapperClass.HandleServiceCall(async () => await MyAsyncMethod(source.Token), source).Result
```

To clarify what is done here:
I am creating a cancellation Token for my Task with a given max TimeSpan and then give this Token to the async Method which should be called.
This call is given as a func into my HandleServiceCall Method. 
This Method will create another CancellationToken with a given greater TimeSpan, which will Run as a delayed Task (task.Delay will just wait until the Token is triggered).
Task.WhenAny will look if the normal async task or the delayed task is finishing first. If it is the delayed one, your maximum time has expired and an exception is thrown.

Greetings
Konstantin

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Timer class, start it when you want it to (beginning of the program presumably), and use some like a simple if statement to stop it, such as *if timer is greater than set time, end program. *

Answer (score 0):

I add small example

```
  static CancellationTokenSource cts;
    static  void Main(string[] args)
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
       Task.Factory.StartNew(test);
       cts.Cancel();
    }

    private async static void test()
    {

        await function(cts.Token);

    }

    static async Task function(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                //mycode
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```